# Trigger on insert or update, which moves the updated record to another table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger on table A as below:
I am trying to move the record which is inserted or updated from table A to table B. A record in table A is updated many times and want to tract every update. Hence table B is exactly the same as table A with just 3 more fields like datestamp, user and id(primarykey)

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[catchupdate]
   ON  Table A
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @userid varchar(128)
    declare @rolereqid varchar(128)
    DECLARE @currDate DATETIME;
        SET @currDate = GETDATE();
        select @userid = system_user

    select @rolereqid = [RoleRequestID] from TableA

    Insert into TableB
    (RoleRequestId, ......list...)
      select * from RoleRequests
      where RoleRequestId = @rolereqid

    Update TableB
      set User_Name1 = @userid, dateupdated = @currDate
      where id = @@IDENTITY
```

Now the record inserted is all the time the same last record of table A. I am not sure if I am catching the recordid correctly, ie the updated record id from table A.
select @rolereqid = [RoleRequestID] from TableA

Answer (score 0):

you should ...

```
select @rolereqid = [RolerequestID] from INSERTED
```

... instead of ...

```
select @rolereqid = [RolerequestID] from TableA
```

that was you should get the RoleRequestID of the newly inserted record. 
i guess you'll have to correct other problems in your sample code also ... for example you select from table "RoleRequest" into TableB ... shouldn't TableA be the source?